# Any way in git, to add all files with only whitespace changes to staging?

Tags: git, whitespace

An update came in from a library we use that, among other things, cleaned up / standardised up newlines at the end of files.  As I consider this change a completely safe change, I'd like to be able to automatically say that any file that has a diff *like*,

```
diff --git a/ExampleFile.cs b/ExampleFile.cs
index abcdef..abcd 100755
--- a/ExampleFile.cs
+++ b/ExampleFile.cs
@@ -88,4 +88,4 @@ namespace com.sixminute
         }

     }
-}
\ No newline at end of file
+}
```

to be put directly into staging, so I only have to deal with / review the "real" files that have changed?  Basically, any file that if I run `git diff -w ExampleFile.cs` on and returns an empty string should be added.

I've looked for a way to do this automatically with git, but I can't see any direct way to be able to do it.  My solution was to write a python helper script (`git` below is just a sh.Command wrapper to the git binary in my shell),

```python
for fname in git.diff('--name-only', '--full-index', 'HEAD').splitlines():
    if '' == git.diff('-w', fname):
        print 'adding', fname
        git.add(fname)
```

But for something like this, I kinda automatically assumed git would have something built in, but if it is, I can't find the details of it in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

man [git-diff](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) says:

> **--ignore-blank-lines**
>
> Ignore changes whose lines are all blank.

try something like this:

```
for fname in $(git diff --name-only --full-index HEAD)
do
   diff=$(git diff -w --ignore-blank-lines)
   [ -z "$diff" ] && git add $fname
done
```

Comment: Hmmm, so that's ignoring whitespace, similar to the `git diff -w` option, but that still doesn't give me any solution to stage those files, which is what I'd like to do.  I also understand about the ignoring file endings, but again, that's not what I want to do either.  I want to stage all files that have *just* whitespace changes, that are safe to commit, to be then left with a dirty workspace that has all the other changes for me to review.

Comment: o, sorry, I didn't pay an attention that it is before the commit.

Comment: Yeah, I'm bringing in external source (Amazon's mobile Unity SDK) manually and there is where the whitespace changes are coming from.

Comment: Yep, upvoted that now, and I've added my own solution in Python.  I won't mark either as correct, as the question is about doing it with `git` directly, not via scripting.

Comment: not for the points but for the knowledge:) , what does the `git` directly mean?

Comment: Your solution uses bash scripting to achieve staging files with only whitespace changes, mine uses Python.  I kinda thought, and am looking for an option like `git add -A` with a filter, `git add -AW`, "Add all with whitespace changes only.".

Answer (score 1):

Submitting my own answer in using Python and the Python sh library (https://github.com/amoffat/sh),

```python
import sh

git = sh.git.bake('--no-pager', _cwd='/Developer/repos/git/example')

for fname in git.diff('--name-only', '--full-index', 'HEAD').splitlines():
    diff = git.diff('-w', fname)
    print diff
    if '' == diff:
        print 'adding', fname
        git.add(fname)
```